# Javascript code is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a JavaScript code. In this the alert is displaying more than one time.

```
<input type="text" name="grouptype" id="grouptype">
<input type="hidden" id="type_id" name="type_id">
<input type="text" id="type_bal" name="type_bal" onfocus="place1(form.grouptype.id,form.type_id.id)">
```

```
function place1(x,y)
{
var place=document.getElementById(x).value;// it hold the value of grouptype
var place_id=document.getElementById(y).value;//it hold the value of type_id
    if(place!="" && place_id=="") {
        document.getElementById(x).focus(); 
        alert("pl. select the livesearch data");
    }
}
```

not only that I used a jQuery code also. The following is the code

```
//<!-- the following commented code is used to move tab index when we press enter-->
$("input[tabindex],select[tabindex], textarea[tabindex]").each(function () {
    $(this).on("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13)
        {
            var nextElement = $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex + 1) + '"]');
            if (nextElement.length) {
                $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex + 1) + '"]').focus();
                $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex + 1) + '"]').select();
                e.preventDefault();
            } else
                $('[tabindex="1"]').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

The above code is used to move focus from one text field to another text field it is working properly when in another text field I kept a focus function named as place1 which I given in the above code is not invoking that place1 function without alert. Then i kept alert. By that the alert message it will was invoking by 3 times. why?

Comment: Just a code quality pointer: `$("input[tabindex],select[tabindex], textarea[tabindex]").each(function () {
    $(this).on("keypress", function (e) {` is redundant, you don't need the .each. `$("input[tabindex],select[tabindex], textarea[tabindex]").on("keypress", function (e) {` is enough - jQuery automatically creates a handler for each element matched by the original selector.

Comment: Regarding your actual question....are you saying that you tried the jQuery code as an alternative to the first code, or is there some other relationship between them? It's not clear. We also can't see how the place1() function is ever called. You say it alerts twice but we have no way of knowing how that's happening because we don't know how you call the function in the first place.

Comment: Why is the question been upvoted?

Comment: <input type="text" id="type_bal" name="type_bal" onfocus="place1(form.grouptype.id,form.type_id.id)"> i am calling place1 from this line that means when this text filed is focused

Comment: if you have extra code please edit your question to include it. Comments are for comment and clarification, not for unreadable code samples. Also it would help if you could answer all of my questions, not just a single one. Finally please state as well whether any errors or warnings occur in your browser's console while you are running your code. If you see any errors etc, please list them in your question. Thankyou.